# How to save the data of resultset in multiple files?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-poi

I have written a program which reads the data from database and writes into excel. My code is as belows...

```
public String ReadRows(String query) throws SQLException 
   {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    File file=new File("src/MyEcel.xlsx");
    String returnString = "";
    Connection c = null;
    int row = 1;

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("url",username,password);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("NewData");           
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);         

        while(rs.next())
        {

           myRow= sheet.createRow(row); 
           row++;
           for (int col = 1; col<ColumnCount(); col++)
           {
              if (rs.getObject(col) == null) 
                {   //code;
                } 
                else
                {   //code                     
                }                   
           }               
            fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
             workbook.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.flush();
            System.out.println("The size of file is "+file.length());
             fileOut.close();                
            //java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);       
       }   
        catch(Exception ex)
          {// ex.printtrace();
             }
```

}}

My doubt is how to handle with large amount of data??? I have found few articles saying SXXSF would deal with this issue. But, it only streams the data into a large file. I need a file which holds only 100rows in each file. So i tried using collections but i'm not able to hold the data...Can you pls help !!

Comment: "I need a file which holds only 100rows in each file"  Do you mean lots of different spreadsheet files, each with 100 rows, or one spreadsheet, with lots of sheets, each with 100 rows, or something else?

Comment: Sorry !! lots of spreadsheets with 100 rows each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep a couple counter variables -- one to hold the number of rows written to the current spreadsheet, say, `rowsWritten`, and one to hold the number of spreadsheets completed so far, say, `spreadsheetsWritten`.

Inside the `while` loop, increment `rowsWritten` on each iteration.  If `rowsWritten` has reached `100`, then write out the current spreadsheet, reset `rowsWritten` to `0`, and increment `spreadsheetsWritten`.  Then, create a new spreadsheet if you're not on the last row overall from the database.  This new spreadsheet should be a different filename, and that's where `spreadsheetsWritten` comes in.  It can be called `"src/MyExcel1.xlsx"`, `"src/MyExcel2.xlsx"`, etc., but of course that's up to you.  Make sure you close the last spreadsheet after the `while` loop is done.